# Is my ruby on rails application being hacked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

My application is sending notification emails thanks to **exception_notification** gem. I am wondering if I am being hacked since the request url is an external url (http://api.ipify.org) and this is hosted on digitalocean. Please see below error details.

```
An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in home#index:

  Missing template home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/var/www/rails_app/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails_app/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@rails_app/gems/ckeditor-4.1.3/app/views"
```

Request:

- URL        : http://api.ipify.org/
- HTTP Method: GET
- IP address : 185.75.56.44
- Parameters : {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index"}
- Timestamp  : 2016-02-29 12:28:52 +0800
- Server : *******.com
- Rails root : /var/www/rails_app
- Process: 29977

Comment: The error just says you have a view template missing. Why do you think you are being hacked?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous that's why I indicate that it is coming from an external url (http://api.ipify.org/) and that is not my domain name.

Answer (score 0):

185.75.56.44 Is Serbia. If you're currently in Serbia, then I think the answer is no - it's probably you trying to view your own website.